# Keras : How to reshape the tensor to desired dimension?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

This is the code snippet I'm using for Char embedding. Eventually, I'm concatenating it with word embedding with dimension [?,100].
I want this char embedding in the similar dimension but not able to achieve it.
I tried using Reshape but didn't work it is giving rank 3 vectors and I tried using Flatten() which giving (?,?) as output dimension.

How can fix this ?

```
input_data = Input(shape=(64,1),name='input')
inner = Conv1D(32, (3), padding='same', name='conv1', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(input_data)
inner = BatchNormalization()(inner)
inner = Activation('relu')(inner)            
inner = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=(2), name='max1')(inner)            
inner = Conv1D(64, (3), padding='same', name='conv2', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(inner)            
inner = BatchNormalization()(inner)           
inner = Activation('relu')(inner)        
inner = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=(2),name='max2')(inner)
inner = Dropout(0.3)(inner)
inner = Conv1D(128, (3), padding='same', name='conv3', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(inner)
inner = BatchNormalization()(inner)
inner = Activation('relu')(inner)
inner = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=(1), name='max3')(inner)
inner = Dense(64, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='dense1')(inner)
output = Dropout(0.3)(inner)
```

**Error**

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 3 but is rank 2 for 'concatenate_token_and_character_vectors/token_lstm_input' (op: 'ConcatV2') with input shapes: [?,16,64], [?,100], [].
```

Concatenating the token vectors and char vectors here

```
            with tf.variable_scope("concatenate_token_and_character_vectors"):

                if self.verbose: 
                    print('embedded_tokens: {0}'.format(embedded_tokens))

                token_lstm_input = tf.concat([output, embedded_tokens], 
                    axis=1, name='token_lstm_input')

                if self.verbose: 
                    print("token_lstm_input: {0}".format(token_lstm_input))
```

**Please Comment down below if you need any other info**

Comment: could you please add the piece of code where you try to concatenate the word embedding

Comment: @MarcoCerliani added the snippet